# how do i search an arraylist for a specific format of a string in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, string.format

I am trying to search an arraylist, not for a value but for a format. I am importing a text file that is inconsistent in formatting. I have successfully imported the information into a `2D arraylist`. Is there a way to scrub the info for a format of a string?

example imported info:

```
14  03-324-27216|14     "1 = 14' 0"" X 3.500""" 14.000  49      3.500   MF AU 210 AS M  0   05-01-15    

14  03-362-50502|14 24543   "1 = 21' 6"" X 3.625""" 21.000  77      3.625   BF GP 212           
            Location REM                                
            V:24543
```

Each line of the imported file may contain multiple dimensions and multiple lines. I would like to start a new Arraylist when the format

```
##-###-#####|##
```

shows up, and add an element any time that

```
"# = ##' #"" x #.###"""
```

show up.

Comment: Regex pattern matching, and loops to traverse the array.

Comment: You can match that input with [`\d\d-\d{3}-\d{5}\|\d\d`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  For more specific assistance, show the code you have for parsing the file and ask a specific question (including error messages and how the results differ from your expectations).

Answer (score 1):

From the two lines you posted it appears that is a space delimited CSV file. The downside is that some 'empty' elements were written as a space.

If you replace spaces with commas (unless they have a space on both sides) you get a properly formatted CSV file.

```
03-324-27216|14, , ,"1,=,14',0"",X,3.500""",14.000,,49, ,, ,3.500, ,MF,AU,210,AS,M,,0, ,05-01-15, ,,
03-362-50502|14,24543, ,"1,=,21',6"",X,3.625""",21.000,,77, ,, ,3.625, ,BF,GP,212, ,, ,, , ,
```

It may be easier to build a custom CSV parser that handles the weird 3 spaces in a row case.

Comment: Could I also loop through the array and search if a string contains the "|" special character to start an array list and the " ' " special character to add to it? I think the roll number "##-###-#####|##" are the only strings with the " | " character and each dimension line is the only string with the " ' " character. in effect I think I would loop through each element and have something like "contains" with a Boolean result to operate on right?